# DEBUG inserting post query SQL with express

Tags: sql, node.js, express

Hello :) as you see in title, I'm using MYSQL with express.

When i try to query POST , i'll get  this err `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '$1' in 'field list'`

I know it's about my columns in query, but i don't know where ...

Or can it be about post requests in my JSON?

**This is my router & query :**

```js
router.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  const sql = `
  INSERT INTO users (nationalcode, stockcode, firstname, lastname, isenable,contractnumber, archive, detail, birthdate,  offlineusername)
  VALUES
  ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6,$7,$8,$9, $10)
  `;

  const {
    nationalcode,
    stockcode,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    isenable,
    contractnumber,
    archive,
    detail,
    birthdate,
    offlineusername
  } = req.body;

  db.query(sql, [nationalcode,
    stockcode,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    isenable,
    contractnumber,
    archive,
    detail,
    birthdate,
    offlineusername
  ], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

**And my schema is :**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nationalcode INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  stockcode VARCHAR(255),
  firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  isenable bool,
  isonline bool,
  contractnumber VARCHAR(255),
  archive numeric,
  detail VARCHAR(255),
  birthdate varchar(255),
  offlineusername varchar(225),
  created_at TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN isenable SET DEFAULT false;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN isonline SET DEFAULT false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you Passed Invalid values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6,$7,$8,$9, $10);  in Sql Query.

Solution1:
Firstly, check your Values(?,?,?,?.....).According to Schema DataType then passed it.
After that modify or change the Db.Query() callback function.
and Then Execute the Query.
Another Simple way Firstly run Insert query PHPMyAdmin Manually. And After that try in Editor,

you can go to this link  https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#readme. 
 for Better Understanding. 
I Hope which might help you in question.

Screenshot Help to Solve the problem.[image]

Comment: Didn't work, Err: ```  argument callback must be a function when provided ```